# How to include a php file from directory named "files" in CakePHP 1.3 folder structure?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have CakePHP 1.3 setup like following
app -config
    -controllers
    -lib
    -models
    -views
    -webroot
       -css
       -files
       -js

Now to include a javascript file in my view file(.ctp) I know that i have to do

```
echo $this->Html->script('manage_products');
```

and it will include it but if i want to include any php file from the files directory which is under webroot folder is there any cakePHP method or helper i can use or do i just require_once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the PHP file is independent of CakePHP then just use `require_once`:-

```
<?php require_once WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS . 'foobar.php'; ?>
```

There is no need to complicate it further than that.

Comment: Just to help others. "Please add the statement in your required view file".